# Каждая буква с новой строчки

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Я хочу сделать у блока `.hint` каждую букву на новой строчке, я могу сделать span'ов для каждой буквы
Но это выглядит как-то костыльно, возможно есть более лучшее решение?

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}

.hint {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 5px 13px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hint span {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hint">
  <span>П</span>
  <span>о</span>
  <span>д</span>
  <span>с</span>
  <span>к</span>
  <span>а</span>
  <span>з</span>
  <span>к</span>
  <span>а</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
body {
  background: orange;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 50%;
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 10px 5px 10px;
}

/*Добавить*/

div {
  width: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>пример</div>
```